# Regulated charge pump design

Tags: charge-pump

I am working with an IC that uses a partially intergrated regulated charge pump. The circuit looks like this:

[image: Charge pump circuit]

It behaves like a voltage doubler. However, when looking at other regulated charge pumps I am coming across much simpler designs such as this on for example:

[image: Other pump circuits]

I understand the wokring of a single-stage charge pump and the fact that they can be chained together. However, the circuit from the first diagram confuses me as it looks like nothing I could find online.

My questions are:

- Why are C2 and C3 connected across D2 and D3?
- What is the purpose of C1?
- What type of charge pump is this?

Comment: In a simple 1 capacitor charge pump, the doubled voltage is available at the output only during one half of the cycle. With this, (disregarding diode voltage drop) when SW1 is tied to Vdd the full doubled voltage is available from C3, while part of it splits from C2 into C1. When SW1 is tied back to ground, half of the doubled voltage is still available at C1 and splits between C1 and C3, therefore about a quarter of the doubled voltage wil be available at the output even during the other half of the pump cycle.

Comment: Just by curiosity, do know how a charge pump works? Your first picture is a very primitive implementation of a charge pump. Think of it as a balloon you're trying to fill with air with a bicycle pump. If you stop pumping, then air gets out. So the faster you pump the bicycle pump, the less air you'll lose in your balloon. The diode is there to prevent any negative ripple.

Comment: What IC is it? And your first schematic doesn't show a "partially intergrated regulated charge pump" rather, it shows a couple of discrete components.